# Resize the WP media Uploader iFrame

Tags: uploads, media-library, media-settings, iframe

I'm trying to customize the look of the iframe that pops up (media uploader).

I've manage to remove some fields etc, but I cannot re-size the frame. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default media box has hard coded HTML values so in order to alter the CSS for it you you have 2 options.

1. Enqueue your own CSS and override the values
2. Disable `media-views.css` completely and load a custom stylesheet.

To enqueue your own style:

```
function blah_admin_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'blah_admin_css', path to your custom.css );
}
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'blah_admin_css' );
```

Now just add whatever you want to a `custom.css` file to override the CSS values, you might have to use the dreaded `!important`.

To completely disable the admin CSS from loading for the media box you need to hook into `wp_default_styles` and the name which happens to be `media-views`.

For example:

```
function remove_media_style($wp_styles ){
    $wp_styles->remove('media-views');
}
add_action('wp_default_styles', 'remove_media_style');
```

You should use a plugin to do this since you just have to disable it to revert back to the original style.

ps. There is a 3rd option, just use javascript, and generally speaking all 3 options are a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem is I am already pulling in a custom CSS file BUT the styles I want to change are inline which means the CSS file just gets over written

Comment: The default media box styles aren't inline, you can override them using `!important` unless you have javascript turned off.